# Daylight Saving Time adjustment

Tags: customization

The last discussion on this appears to be a few years old. The current Wordpress rev is now 4.8.1. 
I just noticed the system time was off by an hour. IIRC, WP had a checkbox to adjust for daylight saving. Has this feature been removed? Aside from setting a reminder, is there a simple way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

If you head to Settings->General in the WordPress Dashboard you can select a timezone. For example mine is set to London and states:

*Universal time (GMT) is 2017-08-07 15:46:29. Local time is 2017-08-07 16:46:29.*

*This timezone is currently in daylight saving time.

Standard time begins on: 29th October 2017 2:00 am.*

Comment: Yes. When DST ends will you need to manually go in to WP or does it adjust?

Comment: It should change automatically based on the timezone selected. It wouldn't make sense to have to change it to another timezone based on DST.

Comment: If you choose a city, it should adjust. If you're selecting a manual GMT offset then it won't adjust.